# js addition script not working properly

Tags: javascript, function, math, addition

The following code should print the SUM of x and y.  It works on the W3 editor, but not my Sublime?  I don't understand why.

```js
function add () {
    var x = prompt("Enter a number.");
    var y = prompt("Enter another number.");
    var a = x + y;
    alert(a);
    }
```

```html
<script>
  add();
  </script>
```

The output I get is literally xy.  If I enter x=1 and y=2, I get 12.
I also run into the same problem if I just hit the js code into the body without the function.  I can't find my mistake.  Could it be my editor?

Comment: `prompt` always returns a string. You've to convert the return values to numbers before the math. JS doesn't do automatic type coercion in this case, since `+` operator is used to concatenate strings too.

Comment: @teemu ParseInt method?

Comment: That, or `parseFloat` or unary `+` or `Number` constructor.

Comment: can you explain the difference, please?  All 4 work.  Under the hood there must differences (bytes used, etc?).

Comment: @chignon Here's a full reference to the JavaScript `Number` wrapper object, its properties and its methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make it

```
function add () {
    var x =parseInt(prompt("Enter a number."),10);
    var y = parseInt(prompt("Enter another number."),10);
    if ( !isNaN(x) && !isNaN(y) )
    {
      var a = x + y;
      alert(a);
    }
    else
    {
      alert("One of the numbers is not valid");
    }
}
```

you need to parse the string received from the prompt to a integer first.

Comment: Don't forget the radix.

Comment: Also don't forget to check for `NaN`.

Comment: @j08691 and War10ck, thanks for pointing out, made the changes

Comment: checking for NaN I have difficulty with...example please?

Comment: @chignon NaN stands for Not a number. `isNaN` checks if the passed argument is a number or not.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I know what isNaN is...I'm just not comfortable in my coding ability to test for it. How would you use it in this instance?

Comment: @chignon Extending on what _@gurvinder372_ said, passing in "hello" as an input to one of the prompts for instance would result in `NaN` when parsed because the string "hello" cannot be parsed to an integer. So to test this out pass a string (doesn't matter what) and a number. You'll get the `alert("One of the numbers is not valid");` from the code above if you copied and pasted it into your program.

Comment: @War10ck I understand conceptually what isNaN does.  I'm just not the greatest at using the isNaN() method I'm still very much a newbie (obv)!.  I was after an example of its implementation...which you sorta provided! Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

The values are strings so the `+` operator is treating it as string concatenation. Use `parseInt()` to generate integers, then do the addition:

```js
function add () {
    // Best to include radix with parseInt
    var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number."), 10);
    var y = parseInt(prompt("Enter another number."), 10);
    // Quick and dirty check for NaN
    if(!(x != x) && !(y != y)) {
        var a = x + y;
        alert(a);
    } else {
        alert("Both inputs must be valid integers!");
    }
}

add();
```

Just for fun, here's an even shorter method:

```js
function add () {
    var x = +prompt("Enter a number."),
        y = +prompt("Enter another number.");
    alert((!(x != x) && !(y != y)) ? x + y : "Both values must be integers!");
}

add();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use use:

```
function add () {
    var x = Number(prompt("Enter a number."));
    var y = Number(prompt("Enter another number."));
    var a = x + y;
    alert(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because prompt returns type string. Try using the

```
parseInt()
```

function. So

```
var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number."));
```